# How can I ensure my wireless keyboard works on my Android TV box?

Tags: keyboard, external-keyboard, android-tv

I just bought a wireless keyboard  (Rii mini 28). When I plugin the receiver into my windows laptop, it just works. I can type things in notepad and move the cursor.

But I bought it for my Android device: Ugoos UT4 OCTACORE ANDROID TV BOX. So I plugged the receiver into one of the USB ports. But I can not use it the way I used it for Windows. My android device ignores all my actions.

Any idea how I ensure my wireless keyboard works on my Android TV box?

Comment: Is the keyboard designed for Android devices? You may be suffering from lack of drivers.

Comment: Yes, https://www.amazon.com/Rii-Wireless-Remote-Keyboard-Laptop/dp/B00HR4XH5W

Comment: You have to pair them first. What is said in the manual?

Comment: The keyboard manual said that the keyboard is found and installed automatically (which is really the case for windows and there it just works). The Android device manual does not explain anything about this. Any idea how I should pair?